# Is there anyway to search active SQLite database as Full Text Search

Tags: php, sqlite, full-text-search

I have an active website that connected with SQLite database. And on search page, I make it as:

```
$sql = “select * from table where column1 like “\%$q%”\”;
```

However, after I try to search with `52 brand ceiling fan`. A result gives empty. But if search with `brand 52 ceiling fan`. There has a result to show.

I know Full Text Search is performance way to solve this issue. But with my active website and database. Is there anyway to working without creating new database?

Thank

Comment: Explode `$q` on spaces then build a `LIKE '%$words[0]%' OR LIKE  '%$words[1]%'` etc...

Comment: Humm.. what if most of the records started with **brand**? Maybe this is better :`LIKE '%$words[0]%' AND LIKE '%$words[1]%'`

Comment: External content fts tables will be of interest: https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html

Comment: I trying to explode $q as $qq = explode(" ", $q);. However, how to using all array variables that explode from $q? Because $q may be more than [2] or [3].